# Error with Android Studio 1.0.2 when trying to run the default project

Tags: android

I am running Android Studio 1.0.2 and get the following messages when I try to run the default project:

> C:\Users\ljay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd
>   Nexus_4_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB Failed to create Context 0x3005 emulator:
>   WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software
>   renderer. could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB emulator: WARNING: Requested
>   RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced
>   to 1152MB. Cannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument

Comment: Are you running an avd?

Comment: Are you running the emulator on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I faced this issue disabled the snapshot. So go to AVD Manager → select the device → click *Edit* and uncheck the *Enabled* checkbox.

Alternatively you could try do delete the snapshot data. You find it usually in your home directory at `.android/deviceName.avd/`. Delete all files `snapshots.img*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the Use Host GPU option.

AVD Manager → select device → Edit and uncheck "Use Host GPU"